# Unable to show notification when application in foreground

Tags: android, firebase, notifications, android-notifications, firebase-cloud-messaging

I am trying to get push notifications using FCM in my android application the code is working fine when notification is sent from FCM console it works fine both in foreground and background, but when I send notifications using curl through FCM I am getting data which is visible in logcat but notification is displayed only when application is in background and does not show up when application is in foreground. `onMessageReceived` is called every time when data is pushed from FCM but notification is not visible when application is in foreground.

```
 private void sendNotification(String body , Map<String,String> data) {

        int finalSecId = Integer.parseInt((String) data.get("sec_id"));
        int sec = Integer.parseInt((String) data.get("sec"));
        String extra1 = (String) data.get("extra1");
        String extra2 = (String) data.get("extra2");
        Intent intent = new Intent(this,HomeActivity.class);
        intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
        PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(this, 0/*Request code*/, intent, PendingIntent.FLAG_ONE_SHOT);
        //Set sound of notification
        Uri notificationSound = RingtoneManager.getDefaultUri(RingtoneManager.TYPE_NOTIFICATION);


        NotificationCompat.Builder notifiBuilder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(this)
                .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.login_meter)
                .setContentTitle(getString(R.string.app_name))
                .setContentText(body)
                .setAutoCancel(true)
                .setSound(notificationSound)
                .setContentIntent(pendingIntent);

        NotificationManager notificationManager = (NotificationManager)getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
        notificationManager.notify(0 /*ID of notification*/, notifiBuilder.build());
    }
```

Comment: write android:stopWithTask="false" in to FirebaseMessageService in menifest file

Comment: ok lemme check.